# Apache Storm priority of Streams

Tags: apache-storm

I have following Problem. I have an Apache Storm topology which looks like this:

> A -> B -> C

A: is an Spout and got some sequences from a database

B: is splitting this sequences and emits n long sequences

C: computes if the subsequence is in all of the sequences

Now if c sees that a subsequence is not in all sequence it should send a instruction message to B that B can prune some Sequences and must not send all the tupels which are longer then the subsequences which are not in all Lists.

My problem is how can I forward this instruction tupel in the message queue of b.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a cyclic graph:

```java
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.addSpout("A",...);
builder.addBolt("B",...)
  .someConnectionPattern("A") // regular forward connection
  .allGrouping("C"); // cyclic feedback connection 
builder.addBolt("C",...).someConnectionPattern("B")
```

In the example, I used `allGrouping` to distribute the truncate information to all instanced. Depending on you use case, a `fieldsGrouping` might work, too.

Comment: I understand this architecture. But if now B has 10 Messages from A in his queue and then 1 of C comes now in, B must first finish this 10 messages before it got the message of C right? I need that this message of C must be executed first. Or did i dont understand something right?

Comment: You did understand this correctly. However, Storm itself cannot priorities tuples. You could only buffer the 10 tuples from A within B in your own code. Of course, you must know that a C feeback tuples is coming later on -- if you cannot guarantee this, you need a strategy to process the buffered tuples without receiving a C tuple. Or you just accept Storm's behavior; ie, your source is going to emit 1000 tuples, and A has 10 in it's buffer. You just process them before receiving the feedback C tuple. You would still save to process 990 tuples. But this depends on you use case and data rates.